# Removing Formats From Entire Worksheet with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA, I am trying to Clear all Formats all entire of the active Worksheet.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 With ws
           .ClearFormats
 End With
```

But I am getting following error:

[image]

However using the same code with .UsedRange works fine as:

```
With .UsedRange
    .ClearFormats
End With
```

Can you please let me know how fix this to format entire sheet!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`ClearFormats` is a method of a `Range`, wereas `ActiveSheet` is a `Worksheet`

You could use

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearFormats
```

(`Cells` is a range of all the cells on a worksheet)